# Mysql - пересечение интервалов

Tags: sql

Есть объект, которому сопоставлен интервал дат. Например, квартира, которая сдаётся в аренду.

Нужно написать такой запрос, который по переданному интервалу смотрел бы, есть ли в таблице объект, интервал которого не пересекается с переданным (границы не включаются в интервал).

---

Пример:

Квартира сдается с 5 мая по 9 мая - это событие есть в таблице

Я хочу добавить новую бронь, например с 11 до 15 мая.

Запрос смотрит в таблицу и видит, что совпадений по дате нет, и выдает эту квартиру.

Причем если новая бронь с 1 по 5 мая, до запрос тоже должен вывести эту квартиру. С 9 мая аналогично.

[Статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209138/#chapter2) и пресловутая формула 
`` WHERE `start` < @end AND `end` > @start ``, не работает.

Структура таблицы событий

```
id  int(11) AI PK
flats_id int(11) 
reservation_time_start timestamp 
reservation_time_end timestamp
```

Comment: Структуру таблицы мы сами должны придумать?

Comment: `WHERE start < @end AND end > @start` - вы переменные местами не перепутали?

Comment: id int(11) AI PK
flats_id int(11)
real_time_start timestamp
real_time_end timestamp
reservation_time_start timestamp
reservation_time_end timestamp
client_comment varchar(45)
excursion tinyint(1)
interpreter tinyint(1)
personal_driver tinyint(1)
food tinyint(1)
transfer tinyint(1)
rent_car tinyint(1)
rent_laptop tinyint(1)

Comment: @ruslik, перенесите этот комментарий в условие, другим будет проще ответить на ваш вопрос. Комментарии же имеют сокращённое форматирование.

Comment: @ruslik, действительно ли вам требуется `timestamp` тип для интервала, если вы сравниваете только даты, или это необходимая особенность системы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой цели подходит следующее условие:

```
WHERE `start` >= @end OR `end` <= @start
```

Т.е. два интервала не пересекаются, или пересекаются только по границе, если начало первого больше конца второго или конец первого меньше начала второго.

Ваше же условие, наоборот, соответствует пересечению интервалов.

Comment: Спасибо, сам догнал, и мой вариант совпал с вашим